# Evaluating complex integral of Bessel functions

Tags: numerical-methods, complex-integration, bessel-functions

I was reading a research article where I encountered a complex integral $$\theta(t)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{-i\infty}^{-i\infty}z^{-1/2}\frac{I_1(z^{1/2})}{I_0(z^{1/2})}e^{zt}dz$$
Here $z$ is a purely imaginary number and $I_1$ and $I_0$ are Modified Bessel functions of first kind of first and zeroth order respectively.
It is said that the integral can be evaluated numerically using **double exponential formula**. I don't fully understand double exponential formula.

Can anyone shed light on how to tackle this integral?